# How to programmatically leave an Ant Design select on enter click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to figure out how to remove focus/deselect/leave an Ant Design Select on enter click? I have the following component:

```
<Select
    className="role-input"
    mode="multiple"
    value={this.selectedValues[config.key]}
    onChange={(value, options) => this.onRoleChange(value, options, index)}
    placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: config.placeholder })}
    size="large"
    key={index}
    optionFilterProp="children"
    filterOption={(input, option) => option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
    onInputKeyDown={() => console.log('hi')}
>
{roleOptions}
</Select>
```

Right now I `console.log("hi")` when I there's an inputKeyDown. I wonder how can I remove focus/deselect/leave the select on that inputKeyDown. I saw there are some select methods like `blur()` whose description is remove focus, however, there aren't any examples and I can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a `ref` to `Select`. And then call methods on `current`.

```
const selectRef = React.useRef(null);

const handleInputKeyDown = () => {
  if (selectRef.current) {
    selectRef.current.blur();
  }
};

return (
  <Select
    ref={selectRef}
    onInputKeyDown={handleInputKeyDown}
    ...
```